# Connecting Django +1.10 with MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, orm

Does anybody replaced the default database engine in Django (+1.10) for MongoDB in the last months? All the info I get in Google is like 6 or 4 years ago.

The most commons results includes **mongodb-engine** which requires **django-nonrel** (a really old fork from Django 1.5), or **mongoengine**, also an outdated library that give many errors, so when you patch one, you get a new one.

I don't know if there is any "new" way to accomplish this.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: It seems to be not a good idea to use Mongodb with Django since it have one of the best ORM, and you will not use a Django killer feature.

Comment: @vtisnado are you solve this problem?? I am facing same problem in Djnago 1.11 with MongoDB

Answer (score 4):

With several builds and tests using docker to try different combinations of versions, I managed to reach to a stable and working Django MongoDB app using the following versions:

```
Django==1.10.0
pymongo==2.7.1
six==1.10.0
mongoengine==0.9.0
```

After installing the needed libraries, edit your settings.py to update or add the following

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
from mongoengine import *
    connect('database_name', host='host_ip',  port=27017)
```

Change the database name and host ip. It tries to connect to localhost by default if no ip is stated.

Now, running your app should have the database connected and ready for use. 
Check mongoengine [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/index.html) for information on how to use it.

Comment: Can I add data using admin page using this?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to integrate MongoDB and Django. Depending on the strategy you take, you may end up with a headache or sail smoothly!

As a web developer you can take up the challenge of connecting Django to MongoDB in two ways:

**Use a MongoDB compatible model framework**: Use a third party framework like MongoEngine or Ming in your django projects. However will miss out on:

- 1500+ core contributors to the project,
- Hourly fixes and ticket resolution,
- Ramp down on the expertise of existing Django models and ramp up on the new model framework.
- Perhaps the biggest drawback is that your project can’t use any of Django’s contrib models! Forget about using Admin, Sessions, Users, Auth, etc., contrib modules for your project!

**Django SQL to MongoDB transpiler — [Djongo](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)**: The strategy is to translate Django SQL query syntax generated by the Django ORM into pymongo commands. Djongo is a SQL to MongoDB query compiler. It translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document. As a result,

- All Django models and related modules work as is.
- Use Django Admin GUI to add MongoDB embedded documents.
- Djongo provides API extensions to the Django ORM that let you ‘embed’ one document inside another, **like MongoEngine**.

There is an article on [Using Django with MongoDB](https://medium.com/@SiddyZen/using-django-with-mongodb-by-adding-just-one-line-of-code-c386a298e179) by adding just one line of code, if you are looking for more information. Otherwise, you can jump directly into the [djongo documentation](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/mongodb/, there is no production ready MongoDB library. There is a couple of other packages besides the one you've mentioned, like https://github.com/jazzband/django-mongonaut, but they are all in beta, they have a number of issues and they don't work with latest versions of Django.