# django-admin runserver throws error

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have installed

- Django==1.10.0
- pymongo==2.7.1
- MongoDB 2.6
- Python==2.7
- six==1.10.0
- MongoDB 2.6
- mongoengine==0.9.0

in `mysite/mysite/settings.py` i have added,

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'smmis@123#',
            }
}

#start
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
from mongoengine import *
    connect('test')
   # connect('test', host='mongodb://127.0.0.1',  port=50226)
#end
```

when i run `django-admin runserver` it throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 317, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 229, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 223, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 156, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Even though `SECRET_KEY = '9&q3vm=wpl3&r_8vgqch3*$+h*kp+urol&z=!gk*79lhwvjx'` is in `mysite/settings.py`

What am i missing i am new to Django

[image]

Comment: Note that mongoengine 0.9 was released in 2015 and Django 1.10 was released in 2016. I'd be very surprised if they were compatible with each other.

Comment: i referred this post for the combination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178108/connecting-django-1-10-with-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

django-admin doesn't set the settings file you want to use by default.

you can either do `django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings` or you can use `python manage.py runserver` instead (manage.py sets the settings file as part of its helper functionality).

Alternatively, I actually prefer to use django-admin but then I use a lib called `direnv` (https://direnv.net/) to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable within the context of my project folder.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` throws the same error and  `django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings.file`  throws this error `File "/opt/VirEnv_p2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named mysite.settings.file
`

Comment: I'm assuming  you haven't modified your `manage.py` to point to the correct settings file? i've updated the answer with a link to the page for django-admin/manage.py

Comment: are you mentioning this:`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")`  if not kindly specify with sample code

Comment: yes that line sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable

Comment: what happens if you run `django-admin diffsettings`? and can you update your question with a diagram of your project structure in relation to your settings files

Comment: I have added img in my question for your reference

Comment: have you read the documentation I posted? the error `ImportError: No module named mysite.settings.file` is because you don't have `mysite.settings.file` you have `mysite.settings`

Comment: sorry, if i try `django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings` it doesnt work